# TPM and ACPI errors listed in dmesg in my Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell Latitude 5511 - spontaneous reboots

Tags: 20.04, reboot, acpi, tpm

In my dmesg I see:

```
$ dmesg|grep tpm
[    0.571377] tpm_tis MSFT0101:00: 2.0 TPM (device-id 0x0, rev-id 78)
[    0.572925] tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead
```

AND

```
$ dmesg|grep Error
[...]
[   15.487650] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Field [WAR2] at bit offset/length 64/32 exceeds size of target Buffer (64 bits) (20210331/dsopcode-198)
[   15.487712] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.AMW0.WMBA due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20210331/psparse-529)
```

I do not know if these errors are associated with each other.
Was anyone able to explain to me easily what these errors are related to? Is it a way to fix them?
Sometimes my laptop is automatically restarting. Perhaps the reason for these errors from logs?

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS 5.13.0-40-generic
Dell Latitude 5511
TPM=ON
SecureBoot=ON
LUKS=ON

Comment: Sorry, have no answer. Can only say: 'me too', at least for the second error message. Also on a Dell, also on 20.04 but a Kubuntu. No idea if it's important. I don't see random restarts.